# Subscribe to specific event in ASP.NET WebHooks

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webhooks

I'm trying to learn ASP.NET WebHooks, but the docs are pretty sparse right now.

What I'm trying to do is subscribe to a specific events. All the samples I can find demonstrate subscribing to all the events, which is not very useful for me.

**EDIT:**

This is the code for subscribing I found in the docs:

```
function subscribe() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/webhooks/registrations",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            WebHookUri: "http://localhost:59927/api/webhooks/incoming/custom",
            Secret: "12345678901234567890123456789012",
            Description: "My first WebHook!"
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, status) { alert(status); },
        failure: function(errMsg) { alert(errMsg); }
    });
    return false;
}
```

What should be the code for subscribing to a "BookAdded" event?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, for anyone else looking for the answer, this is how it should be done:

```
function subscribe() {
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/api/webhooks/registrations",
       data: JSON.stringify({
       WebHookUri: "http://localhost:59927/api/webhooks/incoming/custom",
       Secret: "12345678901234567890123456789012",
       Description: "My first WebHook!",
       Filters: ["BookAdded"]
    }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data, status) { alert(status); },
       failure: function(errMsg) { alert(errMsg); }
   });
   return false;
}
```

Note the **Filters** field added to the ajax statement.

Comment: can we subscribe in asp.net wehbooks receiver itself? I want to subscribe to ebay soap notification, i'm following asp.net.webhook.custom.receiver for it

Comment: The above code subscribe to event from within the webhook project, can we subscribe outside of the current project? may be from a php project? How? I send above request to a custom webhook a fellow colleague has built but I am getting authentication error. in URL I am providing fully qualified URL.

Comment: Yes, it should work without any problems. The authentication error has nothing to do with the webhook mechanism, it's how the server / site is set up.